# Is it possible to get informations at each pixel in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to make an app using android studio which can capture my phone's display in realtime and after that, gets me the information of the picture that I captured. Using this information, I want to display it in OLED using arduino. My plan went like this.

1. Capture in real time using android API(MediaProjection and VirtualDisplay)
2. Get the information of my capture.
3. send the information(ex. color of the pixel to arduino) th arduino
4. show it using OLED display

In sending information, I thought that sending information of each pixel will be nice. But I am having a hard time getting the information of my capture. Is there any way I can get information?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.